# How to do "map chunks", like terraria or minecraft maps?

Tags: c#, algorithm, xna-4.0

Due to performance issues, I have to cut my maps into chunks.
I manage the maps in this way:

```
listMap[x][y] = new Tile (x,y);
```

I tried in vain to cut this list for several "chunk" to avoid loading all the map because the fps are not very high with large map. And yet, when I update or Draw I do it with a little tile range. Here is how I proceed:

```
foreach (List<Tile> list in listMap)
{
    foreach (Tile leTile in list)
    {
        if ((leTile.Position.X < screenWidth + hero.Pos.X) &&
            (leTile.Position.X > hero.Pos.X - tileSize) &&
            (leTile.Position.Y < screenHeight + hero.Pos.Y) &&
            (leTile.Position.Y > hero.Pos.Y - tileSize)
        )
        {
            leTile.Draw(spriteBatch, gameTime);        
        }
    }
}
```

(and the same thing, for the update method).

So I try to learn with games like minecraft or terraria, and any two manages maps much larger than mine, without the slightest drop of fps. And apparently, they load "chunks".

What I would like to understand is how to cut my list in Chunk, and how to display depending on the position of my character. I try many things without success.

Thank you in advance for putting me on the right track!

Ps : Again, sorry for my English :'(
Pps : I'm not an experimented developer ;)

edit :

Thanks to IVlad, I gain 10 fps changing just the loops like this :

```
for (int x = (int)(hero.Pos.X) / tileSize; x < (hero.Pos.X / tileSize) + (int)(screenWidth/tileSize); x++)
{
    for (int y = (int)(hero.Pos.Y) / tileSize; y < (hero.Pos.Y / tileSize) + (int)(screenHeight / tileSize); y++)
    {
        if (x >= 0 && y >= 0 && x <= tileXMax && y <= tileYMax ) {
            grille[x][y].Draw(spriteBatch, gameTime);
        }
    }
}
```

Despite that, the fps are still low and depend on the size of the map instead of the number of visible tiles.

Comment: What exactly is going wrong? Is it rendering too many tiles? Your approach seems correct as you only need to render the tiles actually on screen.

Comment: @SimeonVisser This is the fps which are going very wrong. In fact, when I create a too big map, the Fps are very low (1 or 2 fps). I think, all the list is "loaded" and the game don't like it very much :/.

Comment: While you are rendering only the tiles actually on screen, you are iterating ALL tiles on the map if I'm not mistaken. Shouldn't you find what tile your character is on and only iterate enough tiles around it?

Comment: For example, an `1000x1000` map might be small enough to fit into memory, but you are iterating all of its `1 000 000` tiles each time you render something (you iterate all of them even if you only render a very small part), which definitely explains the 1 or 2 fps issue. You need to only iterate what you render.

Comment: @IVlad I see ! So, i might Use a "for" iteration instead of a foreach, and this way, loop only on the visible tiles. Yeah, I think it should work. Thank you :) I'm trying this !

Comment: @IVlad So I changed my 2 foreach with 2 for (in my update and draw method) http://pastebin.com/0ekw5gCp, but maps bigger than about 200 000 tiles (1000*200) don't load. (or maybe they take too long time to load). I don't understand at all :(

Comment: Did they load before doing this change? Does the change help with the FPS? This should have no effect on the map loading. Are you sure the problem isn't in your loading code or somewhere else?

Comment: @IVlad I see a fps increase of about 10 to 20 fps so it's a good point.But the FPS vary depending on the size of the map instead of the number of visible tiles (200 000=20fps, 20 000 = 200fps). In my loadContent I simply load all the tiles (that's why I think the map takes so much time to load). http://pastebin.com/jFnpJDV5

Comment: What is `Content` in `LoadContent(Content)`? Why are you loading the exact same thing for every tile? You should just load it once and reuse it if all tiles are going to be the same. Can you pastebin your entire actual code for data loading, rendering and updating? Are you running this on a device with a garbage collector?

Comment: @IVlad Here my method : http://pastebin.com/XMWc2ZRz. Content is the content manager (I think this is a XNA class), I don't know how to do without loading it for each tile. I don't think i'm using garbage collector, i'm a beginner in developing so i don't even know how to use it :D

Comment: One more change:  I would compute the low and high bounds outside the loops entirely.  Your code executes a bunch of conditionals inside the inner loop that only need to be executed once.  MinimumX = Math.Max(0, (int)hero.Pos.X/tilesize);...

Comment: @IVlad Ok, I loaded a 1000*1000 tiles map, and the fps is very great (350/500). So thank you ! But The map take too long to load (about 15minutes). I think I must check what is going wrong !

Comment: I'm not sure what to say about loading speed. How many distinct tiles do you have (each tile has an image associated with it, right? How many distinct images do you have?)? Make sure you only load each distinct image once. So if you have 100 tile types, you only need 100 image loads, not 1000x1000 image loads.

Comment: I like the chunk idea. Maybe its a matter of saving the chunk coordinates and the map coordinates. Like have two sets of coordinates. The first chunk coordinate would be 0:0 and it would only loop through that chunk. Then when the player reaches -1:0 it would only loop -1:0 chunk and the 0:0 chunk for the transition but wouldn't loop over a chunk that is a more than a chunk away.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first thing you should do is, just as with the Draw method, only create/load the tiles which are close to you. That should save some time loading the map, and also some memory.

Second thing you could do, instead of having a Draw function for the tile, with a reference to the texture in each, is drawing them directly from outside, just like:

```
//in the load method...
tileTextures = //a list/dictionary with all textures for tiles

for (int x = minX; x < maxX; x++)
    for (int y = minY; y < maxY; y++)
    {
        spriteBatch.Draw(tileTextures[list[x,y].TextureID], list[x,y].Position);
    }
```

This could or could not be useful, depending on how you handle data.

Another thing that could help you is about the colid rectangle. If you are using it to make collision detection, maybe it's better to make that detection by yourself, for example:

```
void CheckCollision(Rectangle character)
{
    int size = 16;
    if (character.Right > this.Position.X &&
        character.Left < this.Position.X + size &&
        character.Bottom > this.Position.Y &&
        character.Top > this.Position.Y + size)
    {
        //Character is colliding with tile
    }
}
```

Basically, everything that reduces the amount of memory allocated by one tile will be good when in big maps.

Comment: In fact, I don't think I can Draw the tiles from the outside, all my lists/dictionaries of texture are in the tile class. Do you think I'll gain fps if I do all outside the class ? Thank you for the Collision, you are right, Colid rectangle is for them but nothing is done for the moment. It is putting me on the right track, thank you :)

Comment: Well, as I said, it depends on how you handle data. You could perfectly do it inside, i just recommend you to keep as many data outside of that class as you can. For example, if the dictionary is inside the tile class, that's one reference. The texture is another one, and so on... These are extra bytes, which get multiplied by the number of tiles, so 2 references = 8 bytes per tile - 2M tiles means 16Mb extra, which could or could not be good. If you can have like a TileManager with all textures there, and retrieve them when you want to draw, I think that would be good.

Answer (score 0):

I have had this kind of problem. I experienced lag on my game because I was calling the map tile like this.

```
var mapTile = map.data[mapX + ":" + mapY];
```

All the data for the whole world was stored in that map.data array. I was not using chunks and chunks would have allowed me to loop over a 2d array. Maybe it would help if the loop only looped over the current chunk and maybe the surrounding ones for transitions. So if the map had 100 chunks in it. It would only loop over 9 chunks instead of 100. Here is a flimsy example.

```
for(var x = 0; x < map.chunk[chunk.x + ":" + chunk.y].data[x].length; x++) {
  for(var y = 0; y < map.chunk[chunk.x + ":" + chunk.y].data[x][y].length) {
    //Draw tiles here that are on screen
  }
}
```

This would limit the amount of iterations going on. You may have already set your loop to work like this but just in case you were looping over every tile in the whole world like I was maybe this can help. I'm not a professional game developer and have no formal education so this is probably not a good answer but I hope it helps.